# What is an interface in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A lot of MDN pages describe things as "interfaces" - I was surprised that "interface" wasn't linked to a more explanatory page; it's just described as an "object type" on MDN's [web APIs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20an%20interface%20is,humans%2C%20and%20combinations%20of%20these.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An interface describes the **shape** of an object. (what properties it has, what type of values those properties contain, etc.) It's not an object itself - it's a more abstract description of what a particular object that implements the interface looks like.

For example, in the HTML standard, the [DragEvent interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#the-dragevent-interface) is described as such:

```
[Exposed=Window]
interface DragEvent : MouseEvent {
  constructor(DOMString type, optional DragEventInit eventInitDict = {});

  readonly attribute DataTransfer? dataTransfer;
};

dictionary DragEventInit : MouseEventInit {
  DataTransfer? dataTransfer = null;
};
```

So `DragEvent` is a type of `MouseEvent` (which is another interface). It has a constructor function, so you can call `new` on `window.DragEvent`. When calling the constructor, you call it with the following arguments:

- `type`, which is a `DOMString` (which is basically just any plain string)
- An optional argument of type `DragEventInit` (which the documentation defines), which defaults to the empty object

A DragEvent instance also has a [dataTransfer property](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#datatransfer)

---

Note that the "interface" definition you're linking to is not exactly a JavaScript thing, but more of a thing for web APIs. In other implementations of JavaScript not in browsers (for example, in Node), an interface may mean something different (or nothing at all).

TypeScript, a widely used static type checker for JavaScript, has a very similar notion of interfaces, which describe the shape of a particular object. For example:

```
// Define the shape of a Foo object
interface Foo {
  prop: string;
}

// Create an object that implements Foo
const someFoo: Foo = {
  prop: 'somevalue'
};
```

Comment: why you explain from HTML ? is asking from javascript