# What are interfaces in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, interface, frontend, abstraction

mdn mentions EventTarget interface and several other interfaces.
so what do it exactly means by interface?
Even when I am trying to use interface keyword in js it is showing error?

And what kind of implementation is this:
https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#eventtarget

kindly answer

Comment: Interface is the description of the an API (application programming _interface_). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362268/what-is-an-interface-in-javascript